# SD.begin() fails second time

Tags: sd-card, reliability

When I remove the SD card and try to open a file, I can detect the error properly.

But how do I detect that the card has been replaced after an error? My first thought was to call `SD.begin()` again but it appears that this function returns true exactly once and false thereafter.

Simplified example:

```
void setup() {
  SD.begin(pin); // called exactly once. Works.
}
void loop() {
  // stuff
}
```

But this does not:

```
void setup() {
  SD.begin(pin); // first time calling this function: works.
}
void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  SD.begin(pin); // always fails
}
```

I'd rather not reset the microcontroller just for this.

Comment: I'm looking for a `SD.end()` function somewhere. That is what you need, but I can't find anything in the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is relatively old but still, if you wnat to run  `SD.begin(chipselect);` again first call `if(root.isOpen()) root.close();` I added this to the library. This way `SD.begin(chipselect)` will return `true` if a card is present and `false` when it's not.

Comment: Are you talking about [this fix](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3607)?  AFAIK it's not been merged into master.  Still, a better solution than what I had before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

A **software reset**, while inelegant, was much simpler to implement and debug than trying to add "retry" type functionality to `SD.h`. The other alternative would be to access `SDFatLib.h` or the other lower-level stuff (which `SD.h` is a wrapper for) directly, so if someone has that solution, I'll accept it instead of this one.

## Original

Here is something, which <s>is working well enough for me at the moment:</s> does not reliably work:

```
bool SDState{false};
File LogFile;

bool trySDCard(void)
{
    // sanity check: maybe the SD card is actually here?
    LogFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    delay(10);
    if (LogFile) {
        LogFile.close();
        return true;
    }
    int8_t counter{10};
    while (counter && !SDState) {
        SDState = SD.begin(TFT_CARD_CS);
        Serial.print(counter);
        Serial.print(" ");
        counter--;
        delay(100);
    }   
    Serial.print("SD: ");
    Serial.println(SDState);
    return SDState;
}

void setup() {
    SDState = SD.begin(TFT_CARD_CS);
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    // NB. Simplified a lot (exitMenuMessage(string) is my custom function defined elsewhere)
    switch (state) {
        case SD_RETRY:
            exitMenuMessage(trySDCard() ? "found SD card" : "no SD card");
            break;
    }
}
```

<s>Seems to work</s> Sometimes works if I insert the SD card *while* `trySDCard()` is running.